# Revisiting topicality of stage combat

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions

According to our [help page](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> Questions that should not be asked on Martial Arts include:
>
> Theatrical or stage combat that focus more on theater or entertainment (for role-playing, re-enactments, etc.) (off-topic)

According to our voting to close, [karate stage combat](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/574/adapting-karate-to-stage-combat) is on-topic.

Is stage combat on topic or not? Our help policy should match whatever our actual policy is.

Comment: Hmm... I'm afraid [I've been to blame on this before](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/how-to-avoid-calf-pain-with-heel-stomp), although I did indicate that my feeling was that this was more of a "mechanics of the attack" question than a "how do I fake this?" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find myself torn on this. On one hand, stage combat has as much to do with actual martial arts as movie law has to do with actual courtroom law. On the other hand, as I've argued before, not all martial arts is about combat, and there is a high level of theatricality whether it's methods of cooling down a *roda* in Capoeira or doing a Wu Shu demo involving live weapons. In both cases, I think there are legitimate martial arts questions for "how can I do a proper technique in a way that minimizes the risk of injury for my opponent". On the other hand, "How do I fake a leg scissor takedown for my production of *Rey Mysterio: the Musical*?" should be off-topic.

Comment: OK, I see the conflict. I agree there is some gray area.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too concerned about this - just because one question made it through in the early years of the site doesn't mean we have a problem that needs fixing or a question that needs closing.

It's perfectly normal to have a few experimental questions early on when a site is still developing and the community is finding its way. Despite that rule this question was reasonably well received at the time. If you feel that it should be closed there's nothing to stop you from casting a close vote, then it's up to the community to decide whether it lives or dies.

Comment: I did cast a close vote a few weeks ago and was very surprised when this particular question did not end up closed. That's the motivation behind this meta question.

Comment: @mattm:
Huh. I never saw that one in the queue. I wonder whether this was a case of several people voting to keep it open, or a moderator.

Comment: @SeanDuggan The [close history](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) says you voted to leave open.

Comment: @mattm: ^_^ Shows how bad my memory is... thank you.